# Throws keyword in C++

Tags: c++, exception, stack, throw

Can someone point the right way to do this program with exception handling? It is a program for stacks.

```
1)#include<iostream>
2)#include<stdlib.h>
3)#include<string.h>
4)using namespace std;
5)
6)template<class T>
7)class Stack {
8)private:
9)  int max;
10) int top;
12) T* items;
13)public:
14) Stack(int size) {
15)     max = size;
16)     top = -1;
17)     items = new T[max];
18) }
19) ~Stack(){delete [] items;}
20)
21) void push(T data) throws Exception{
22)     if(full()) {
23)         throw new StackException("Out of space!");
24)     }
25)     items[++top] = data;
26) }
27) T pop(){
28)     if(empty()) throws Exception {
29)         throw new StackException("No more elements to delete"); 
30)     }
31)     return items[top--];
32) }   
33) 
34) bool full() { return top == max-1; }
35) bool empty() { return top == -1; }
36)};
37)
38)int main() {
39)    try{
40)     Stack<int> s(10);
41)     s.push(1);
42)     s.push(2);
43)     cout<<s.pop()<<endl;
44)    } 
45)    catch(StackException e){
46)     cout<<e.what()<<endl;
47)    }
48)    return 0;
49)}
```

Edit : I am getting the following errors. I am new to Exception Handling in C++ , wanted to know if I am doing right --

```
     3stacks.cpp:20:18: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     3stacks.cpp:20:20: error: ‘throws’ does not name a type
     3stacks.cpp:26:8: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     3stacks.cpp:26:10: error: ‘throws’ does not name a type 
     3stacks.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
     3stacks.cpp:44:8: error: expected type-specifier before ‘StackException’
     3stacks.cpp:44:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘e’
     3stacks.cpp:44:23: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘e’
     3stacks.cpp:44:23: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
     3stacks.cpp:44:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

Comment: Any hint on what is going wrong? What problem are you facing? What have you tried?

Comment: "Here's my code, fix it". Well: nah. Do you have any questions about exceptions? btw: Are you mixing C and C++ headers?

Comment: This isn't Java buddy.

Comment: Using exception specifications is [not recommended](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `StackException` anywhere in your program. You have to create it yourself. Also strip `throws Exception` from your function signature, since you never defined that type either (and it's called `throw Exception`).

Furthermore it isn't really necessary to state what exceptions are possible in the signature, but it's better to state that a function will never throw (using `noexcept` in C++11). State possible exceptions in the documentation. Furthermore, you missed a possible `bad_alloc`.

All in all, strip all your code and use `std::stack` from `<stack>` and strip those C libraries. However, here is a example how you could do it:

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
private:
    int max;
    int top;
    T * items;
public:
    struct out_of_space{};
    struct empty_stack{};
    Stack(int size) {
        if(size)
            max = size;
        top = -1;
        items = new T[max];
    }
    ~Stack(){delete[] items;}

    void push(const T & data){
        if(full()) {
            throw out_of_space();
        }
        items[++top] = data;
    }
    T pop(){
        if(empty()){
            throw empty_stack();
        }
        return items[top--];
    }   

    bool full() const { return top == max-1; }
    bool empty() const { return top == -1; }
};

int main() {
    try{
     Stack<int> s(10);
     s.push(1);
     s.push(2);
     cout<<s.pop()<<endl;
    } catch(const Stack<int>::out_of_space& e){
     cout<< "stack out of space" <<endl;
    } catch(const Stack<int>::empty_stack & e){
     cout<< "stack is empty" <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To actually use `e.what()` you would have to implement it yourself. Or you could inherit `std::exception`, overload it and just catch `const std::exception&`.

Comment: I wanted to implement one myself that is why I did not use libraray..

Comment: @Fox: I just added an example for that case. If you ever need to use any C headers don't use `library.h` but `clibrary`, e.g. `cstdlib`. btw, your logic in `pop` was broken. Assignment: Why is `--top` correct and `top--` wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. top-- is correct because you have to return the element and then decrement the position ..

Comment: @Fox: Oops, I accidentally forgot that you were using `top = -1` as initial value. In this case `top--` is correct, yes.